# How to think using while creating sets (Union, Intersection, Issubset)

Tags: python, set

I'm stuck on a school project:

> Create a set that presents the following:
>
> Result of test in English and Spanish:
>
> ```
> Name       ENG     SP
> Alex       A       A
> Bart       F       A
> Nick       A       A
> Andrea     A       F
> Jeff       A       A
> ```
>
> Create a program that shows:
>
> 1. Number of students that passed English or Spanish.
> 2. Number of students that passed both English and Spanish
> 3. Number of students that didn't pass anything (got an F)
>
> You're supposed to use
>
> ```
> union, intersection, issubset
> ```
>
> to show 1-3. The names of the students shall also be included.

The first thing that I've tried is to create som form of list using for loops.

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet

name = OrderedSet(['Alex', 'Bart', 'Nick', 'Andrea', 'Jeff'])
eng = OrderedSet(['A', 'F', 'A', 'A', 'A'])
sp = OrderedSet(['A', 'A', 'A', 'F', 'A'])


print('Result of test in English and Spanish:')
print('Name', '\t', 'ENGLISH', '\t', 'SPANISH')

for n in name:
    for e in eng:
        for s in sp:
            print(n,'\t',e,'\t\t', s)
        break
```

which gives me the output:

```
Result of test in English and Spanish:
Name     ENGLISH     SPANISH
Alex     A       A
Alex     A       F
Bart     A       A
Bart     A       F
Nick     A       A
Nick     A       F
Andrea   A       A
Andrea   A       F
Jeff     A       A
Jeff     A       F
```

Is there any way of giving the correct OrderedSets on the right places? Or is it too advanced for the task itself? Should I go with another method and convert to set later when I need to call the functions?

What do I need to do to make it print this once? I tried the `range`/`len` functions.

I understand the outcome of Union, Intersection and issubset, what they do, just need to be able to put them into the code but I'll get to that once I get some better understanding of how to think.

Comment: I don't think you need `OrderedSet`, a regular set should be sufficient.

Comment: Also note that it says "create **a** set", so 1 not 3 (although I'm not sure how that is meant to work).

Comment: You probably don't want sets of `A`'s and `F`'s. Just sets of names that got a particular grade in a particular subject. Then use the intersection/union/subset to get all of the groupings.

Comment: Instead of creating separate sets, which will give you the problem of figuring out how to manipulate them all together, think about creating a single set of "students and their results". If you have a set of students with their results, you're able to answer all three questions by applying the provided operations. You wouldn't be applying the operations to a single set of course, so you will need a way to select subsets based on some distinguishing aspect, like "only students that passed Spanish".

Comment: Note that even though it does say to create *a* set, you can't do intersection/union/subset with just one set.

Comment: Are you aware that the builtin `set` type already has methods for `union`, `intersection` and subset testing?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback and your time.
I've read everything and put some into the code (will post MY solution down below).
Helped alot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone that put some time into this

Here's what I came up with (There's probably a way to make it look better or other ways to make it cleaner) but I'm guessing that it will work good enough for the task.

´´´

```
students_and_result = set(['Alex\tA\t\tA', 'Bart\tF\t\tA', 'Nick\tA\t\tA', 'Andrea\tA\t\tF', 'Jeff\tA\t\tA'])
students_passed_english = set(['Alex\tA\t\tA', 'Nick\tA\t\tA', 'Andrea\tA\t\tF', 'Jeff\tA\t\tA'])
students_passed_spanish = set(['Alex\tA\t\tA', 'Bart\tF\t\tA', 'Nick\tA\t\tA', 'Jeff\tA\t\tA'])
students_fail_any = set(['Bart\tF\t\tA', 'Andrea\tA\t\tF']) #Creating the lists
print('The result of tests in English and Spanish')
print('Name', '\t', 'ENG', '\t', 'SP')

spe = students_passed_english #probably not necessarry to create those.
sps = students_passed_spanish
sar = students_and_result
sfa = students_fail_any

for x in sar:
    print(x)#This is the whole list of set's

print('\n')

y = (spe.intersection(sps)) #Find students that passed both
print('Students that passed both classes:')
print('Name', '\t', 'ENG', '\t', 'SP')
for G in y:
    print(G)
Amount = len(y)
print('Number of Students:',Amount)

print('\n')

print('Students that passed English or Spanish:')
print('Name', '\t', 'ENG', '\t', 'SP')
m = sar.union(spe)#Getting the studets that passed classes regarding of which class.
for b in m:
    print(b)
Amount1 = len(m)
print('Number of students:', Amount1)

print('\n')

print('Students that failed atleast one class:')
print('Name', '\t', 'ENG', '\t', 'SP')
a = sfa.issubset(sar)
if a == True:#if the subset is True it prints the names, grades and amount of students.
    for k in sfa:
        print(k)
Amount2 = len(sfa)
print('Number of students:', Amount2)
```

´´´

```
Which gave me the output:

The result of tests in English and Spanish
Name     ENG     SP
Andrea  A       F
Jeff    A       A
Nick    A       A
Bart    F       A
Alex    A       A


Students that passed both classes:
Name     ENG     SP
Alex    A       A
Nick    A       A
Jeff    A       A
Number of Students: 3


Students that passed English or Spanish:
Name     ENG     SP
Andrea  A       F
Jeff    A       A
Nick    A       A
Bart    F       A
Alex    A       A
Number of students: 5


Students that failed atleast one class:
Name     ENG     SP
Andrea  A       F
Bart    F       A
Number of students: 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: it is interesting that being set the **requirement** to use `union`, `intersection`, `issubset`  offers minimal benefit over the dataframe method.  Would there be a gain for a much larger dataset ?

Comment: @D.L My guess would be that it depends on the code, but for this task it seems unnecessary imo. But I'm new to this so seems better to leave that question for a experienced person

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using comprehensions instead of writing the loops out, but encourage you to do what you are comfortable with.

I changed the names and english_grades and spanish_grades so we can ensure that the code handles the case of getting two Fs.

There is probably simpler ways to accomplish this, but it is the method I would approach to utilize the requested `union, intersect, issubset`.

```
names = ['Alex', 'Bart', 'Nick', 'Andrea']
english_grades = ['A', 'F', 'A', 'F']
spanish_grades = ['A', 'F', 'F', 'A']

# combine the data:
combined_grades = zip(names, english_grades, spanish_grades)

# all students as a set
all_students = set(names)
# get the sets of students that got an A:
english_a_students = [name for name, english_grade in zip(names, english_grades) if english_grade == 'A']
spanish_a_students = [name for name, spanish_grade in zip(names, spanish_grades) if spanish_grade == 'A']
# intersection (and):
both_a_students = set(english_a_students).intersection(set(spanish_a_students))
# union (or):
either_a_students = set(english_a_students).union(set(spanish_a_students))
# students who get at least one F (all that are in all_students but are not in both_a_students):
at_least_one_f_students = all_students.difference(both_a_students)

# print confirmation that all the outputs are in fact subsets of all_students:
print(f"""
both_a_students is a subset of all_students: {both_a_students.issubset(all_students)}
either_a_students is a subset of all_students: {either_a_students.issubset(all_students)}
at_least_one_f_students is a subset of all_students: {at_least_one_f_students.issubset(all_students)}
""")

# print the results for the questions:
print(f"""
Names of students that passed at least one course: {either_a_students} (Count: {len(either_a_students)})
Names of students that passed both courses: {both_a_students} (Count: {len(both_a_students)})
Names of students that did not pass in at least one course: {at_least_one_f_students} (Count: {len(at_least_one_f_students)})
""")
```

Comment: Thanks!

So I've studied this code and took some elements from it which helped me to get a working code, will post down below!

Answer (score -2):

The code in the question ends up looking like a dataframe and if so, prefer to use this answer:
(there are other methods too).

```py
import pandas as pd

tr = {
    'name': ['alex', 'bart', 'nick', 'andrea', 'jeff'],
    'eng': ['a', 'f', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'sp': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'a']

}

df = pd.DataFrame(tr)

def pass_items(a, b, type):
    ''' function to determine conditions'''
    if type=='or':
        if (a!='f') or (b!='f'): return 1
        else: return 0
    if type=='and':
        if (a!='f') and (b!='f'): return 1
        else: return 0
    if type=='fail':
        if (a=='f') and (b=='f'): return 1
        else: return 0
        

# all the answers
df['or'] = df.apply(lambda r: pass_items(r['eng'], r['sp'], 'or'), axis=1)
df['and'] = df.apply(lambda r: pass_items(r['eng'], r['sp'], 'and'), axis=1)
df['fail'] = df.apply(lambda r: pass_items(r['eng'], r['sp'], 'fail'), axis=1)


print(df)
print('----')
print('passed at least one:', df['or'].sum())
print('passed at both:', df['and'].sum())
print('passed none:', df['fail'].sum())
```

The result:

```
     name eng sp  or  and  fail
0    alex   a  a   1    1     0
1    bart   f  a   1    0     0
2    nick   a  a   1    1     0
3  andrea   a  f   1    0     0
4    jeff   a  a   1    1     0
----
passed at least one: 5
passed at both: 3
passed none: 0
```

Comment: Thanks! So I've studied this code and took some elements from it which helped me to get a working code, will post down below!